# No wifi adapter found

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, broadcom

It happened me two or three more times, but every time I have to solve it differently. I don't do anything and suddenly my WiFi doesn't work. Now I have Ubuntu 20.04, and I tried to install *dkms* and *bcmwl* from an external USB.
The dkms file went good, but when installing bcmwl by using

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/bcmwl*.deb
```

I got a message saying that there were processing errors:

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Any improvement? Or maybe another method to try to solve it?